# Python - Print last string after line.split

Tags: python, string, split, line

Is there a easy way to print the last string after you've split?

Input File:

```
Name:DOB:Age 
Name:Name2:DOB:Age
```

I want the name and age...

So...

```
string = line.split(':')
print(string[0] + string[xxxx])
```

Is there anything that goes where xxxx is to always print the last string?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `string[-1]` to get the last element in your list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = line.split(':')
print(string[0] + string[-1])
```

Comment: string = line.split(':')[-1]
this to get straight last element